# Different way of using LINQ in joining a single table

Tags: vb.net, linq

Given the table structure of ProductCategories...

```
    ProductCategoryID
    ParentProductCategoryID
    Name
    ModifiedDate
```

Is there any other way to write a query for listing all parent categories and their subcategories besides the following...

```
    From categories In context.ProductCategories
    Let subcategories = categories.ProductCategories
    Where subcategories.Any()
    Select categories.Name, subcategories = (From sub In subcategories 
                                             Select sub.Name)
```

Comment: Your linq query does not match the table structure. Do you have a typo?

Comment: Why have you tagged this [linq] and [vb6]? There's no [linq] in [vb6].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
From category in context.ProductCategories
    Group category By key1 = category.ParentProductCategoryID, key2 = category.ProductCategoryID Into Group
    Select New With {.ParentProductCategoryID= key1, .ProductCategoryID = key2}
```